# How to replace specific lines in a text file

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I have a text file like this.

```
...
# xxx start
...
# xxx end
...
```

I want to replace the lines between `# xxx start` and `# xxx end`.
If the `# xxx start` does not appear, append `# xxx start` and `# xxx end` at the end of the file.
Is there any way to do it with shell?

Comment: Do it with `awk`.

Comment: What do you want to replace them with?

Comment: @Barmar I think it can be done with sed, but I do not know how to get the line number of the `# xxx start`

Comment: Why do you need the line number? Just use `/# xxx start/,/# xxx end/` as your address range.

Comment: But adding the lines at the end if they weren't found will be hard with `sed`. it's easy with `awk` because you can set a variable and check it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the lines between `# xxx start` and `# xxx end` with sed. Then append it at the end of the file. Thanks @Barmar.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '/# xxx start/,/# xxx end/d' file
echo '# xxx start' >> file
curl url >> file
echo '# xxx end'
```